# JavaScript Not getting an updated value when using screen.width or screen.availWidth in a function which is called by setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Expected behavior:

1. `setInterval` calls `getScreenWidth()` every 2 sec.
2. `getScreenWidth()` gets the current width of the (browser) screen.
3. Width is logged into console.
4. We change the screen width, by clicking the 'Restore Down' button (beside Minimize) and then altering using mouse pointer.
5. We see an update in the console output.

Output:

```
"1536"
```

The output is always a constant value. (in my case 1536)

I was trying this code on CodePen, and I've tried:

1. Resizing the output window. (changing it's width)
2. Resizing the browser. (changing width and even height)

The HTML:

```
<div id="demo"></div>
```

The script:

```
"use strict";
console.clear();

function getScreenWidth() {
    return screen.availWidth;
    // I've also tried screen.width
}

const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
let count = 0;

const intervalId = setInterval(function () {
    demo.innerHTML = getScreenWidth();
    console.clear();
    console.log(demo.innerHTML);
    console.log(count);
    count++;

    if (count > 30) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, 2000);
```

Since `setInterval` is indirectly calling `getScreenWidth()` every 2 sec, shouldn't `screen.width` be a fresh value every time?

If I assume that it's a fresh value, then does that mean `screen.width` doesn't equal the current width of the browser window?

Note: The `count` variable in the code is just to stop `setInterval` from running indefinitely in the background.

Comment: How does a monitor change its width? I think you meant to use `window` not `screen`? https://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/

Comment: @evolutionxbox so does screen.width imply the monitor width and not the browser window width? Doesn't screen.width is shortened form of window.screen.width, with the window being a browser object?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/width)?

Comment: @tomerpacific yes, `clientWidth` did the trick.

Comment: @ChinmayGhule yes. Screen implies the monitor/device width https://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/#device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen):

> The Screen interface represents a screen, usually the one on which the current window is being rendered, and is obtained using window.screen.

Thus, the screen object here is represents the device output display, and not the browser window.

Again, [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/width):

> The Screen.width read-only property returns the width of the screen in pixels.

Thus, `screen.width` (or `window.screen.width`) does not give us the browser window width, but it's rather the screen (device output screen) width, which obvious would not change.

To get the width of the browser window, we need to use `Element.clientWidth`.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) once again:

> The Element.clientWidth property is zero for inline elements and elements with no CSS; otherwise, it's the inner width of an element in pixels. It includes padding but excludes borders, margins, and vertical scrollbars (if present).

> When clientWidth is used on the root element (the  element), (or
> on  if the document is in quirks mode), the viewport's width
> (excluding any scrollbar) is returned.

Just changing `getScreenWidth()` would do:

```
function getScreenWidth() {
    return document.body.clientWidth;
}
```

Now the console output changes when the width of the browser window changes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same screen width :)

Anyway, you don't need `setInterval` you can change it every time the browser is resized using the window `onresize` event:

```
window.onresize = function() {
  screen.width; // 1536 / 1530 etc.
};
```

You also cannot get the browser width (with `screen.width`)

But you can easily get it using jQuery's `.width()` function:

```
$(window).width();
```

Here's a working example (using jQuery):

```js
"use strict";
console.clear();

function getScreenWidth() {
  return $(window).width();
}

const demo = document.getElementById("demo");

window.onresize = function() {
  demo.textContent = getScreenWidth();
  console.clear();
  console.log(demo.textContent);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

Edit: You also cannot resize the browser window with JavaScript. This would be a huge security issue, and you should be glad it's not possible.

Comment: I don't know jQuery. The question I have is why does `screen.width` (which basically is `window.screen.width`) gives the width of the screen (i.e. the monitor or the device) instead of the document width, given that `screen.width` comes under the window object.

Comment: @ChinmayGhule Oh, well screen.width only returns the width of the screen, not the browser window. And also, jQuery is just JavaScript with pre-made functions, it's not very hard to use jQuery, and I also provided you an example with jQuery.

Comment: Here I see no need to use jquery. Just use `document.body.clientWidth`.

Comment: @ChinmayGhule what if the body or root element is set to a specific width/height?

Comment: As per my experiment, once we hard-code a fixed value to body width, the same value is returned as output. Resizing doesn't make sense at that point, since the screen begins scrolling horizontally when the window size gets smaller.